# Single PC Volunteer Time Tracking Software

Tags: windows, project-management, timer

I am currently doing research on a program for a non-profit organization.  They need a way to easily track the time different people work.  The problem is they have a lot of volunteers and only one PC for the volunteers to sign in on.  Is there a piece of software that can let someone click their name (or add themselves to the database) when they come in and click their name as they go out and record the time between for multiple people at a time?

**Edit** 
Windows is the OS the base computer is running.
The Budget is $300 for the next 12 months

Comment: What OS must it run on? Any price limit? Any specific features needed (and any others nice-to-have)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, I found this piece of software:
www.trackitforward.com 
Track It Forward is another time-keeping software that appears to be able to do the job.  It includes a clock-in and clock-out mechanic for easy volunteer time tracking.
Pros:
 
-Simple volunteer add in
-Clock-in/Clock-out time tracking
-Kiosk based
-Mobile devices can be used as kiosks

Cons:
-No evidence of a way to institute projects
As far I understand this software can be acquired free of charge for non-profits and is reasonably priced for most other companies.  It is focused on tracking the time different volunteers (or employees) work, thus the number of unique users that it allows you to have is basically unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.paymoapp.com/

This is a very low cost piece of software. All you have to do is log into it with a computer and you and you can start tracking time. Plus, there is an android and iOS app that come with it. The first user is free, after that, it is $5 per person per month. Very good for small teams

Comment: While this is a nice piece of software, I'm afraid it will not work for what I need.  There will be a cycle of Volunteers in addition to the regular staff.  They are looking to learn who gives what time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know anything else. Any "free" time keeping software will only permit 1 user. For paymo, you could have a set number of volunteer accounts. Give them generic names (like volunteer 1, 2, 3) and everytime someone leaves, change the password.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [elapseit](https://elapseit.com/).

The volunteers can use a single PC, but they will have to open the application in different browsers.